# Data display like monthly Report in tabular form in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database table here Database image

[image]

I need to display the attendance data in tabular form on monthly basis selection. The output table in php codeigniter should be like: php report

[image]

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one thing in your php report table, headers aren't months these are just random dates. I think you wanted to show P/A of each student of each month, right?

Comment: no Bro. The headers are dates, I am selecting the month and the report shows attendance of all students of all dates of the month taken. They are not rendom dates, the are the a_date field from the database table

Comment: Where is the code? what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO isn't a free coding service. You need to try solve your issue yourself first. If you get stuck, you need to show us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Wanna do it in CI active record or doing it in core php?

Comment: I am doing in CI

Answer (score 0):

Hi the following is one of the ways to achieve the solution your looking out for

> **NOTE :** Just for the sake of demonstration I have included the database query in controller. Make sure you place it in Models folder.

```
$attendanceRecords = $this->db->get('attendance');
$attendaceDetails = array();
if($attendanceRecords->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($attendanceRecords as $key => $attendance){
        if(!isset($attendaceDetails[$attendance['stud_id']])){
            $attendaceDetails[$attendance['stud_id']][$attendance['a_date']] = $attendance['a_status'];
        }else{
            $attendaceDetails[$attendance['stud_id']][$attendance['a_date']] = $attendance['a_status'];
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will create the loop in the following format

```
$attendaceDetails[
    /* Key is student id */
    [1] => 
        /* Attendance respective to that date */
        ['2017-11-01'] => 'P',
        ['2017-11-02'] => 'P',
        ['2017-11-03'] => 'P'
    [2] => 
        ['2017-11-01'] => 'P',
        ['2017-11-02'] => 'A',
        ['2017-11-03'] => 'A'
]
```

Now you can loop into the no of working days. For eg

```
$workingDays = ['2017-11-01', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-04'];
/* This will get all the keys of the attendaceDetails ie student id */
$studentIds = array_keys($attendaceDetails);

/* Loop all student ids and check whether he was present for the working days or not */
foreach($studentIds as $studentId){
    foreach($workingDays as $workingDay){
        if(isset($attendaceDetails[$studentId][$workingDay])){
            echo 'Present';
        }else{
            echo 'Absent';
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: i will see to it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In case if it helps you then dont forget to mark the answer as accepted, So that it will help others too. In case any queries please let me know